# mysql server won't start

Tags: mysql

I had a master with two slaves replicating. I added two more DBs in `my.cnf` for replication and did the standard procedure like lock the table for read, back up and restored the DBs to slaves. Now I am trying to restart my master MySQL server and getting error:

```
MySQL manager or server PID file could not be found!       [FAILED]
Starting MySQL.Manager of pid-file quit without updating fi[FAILED]
```

The output from the error log is as follows:

```
100914 09:22:43 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/var
100914  9:22:43 [Warning] The syntax '--log' is deprecated and will be removed in MySQL 7.0. Please use '--general_log'/'--general_log_file' instead.
/usr/local/mysql/libexec/mysqld: File '/usr/local/mysql/var/mysql-bin.index' not found (Errcode: 13)
100914  9:22:43 [ERROR] Aborting

100914  9:22:43 [Note] /usr/local/mysql/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

100914 09:22:43 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql/var/mysql1.sitelms.org.pid ended
```

I have the file `/usr/local/mysql/var/mysql-bin.index` and it does exist but `/usr/local/mysql/var/mysql1.sitelms.org.pid` file does not exist. Can someone help me? I don't know what happened here.

Comment: Why would you restart your master server?  What changes did you make to the master's configuration?  If you had an operational replication configuration the master should not have required any configuration changes.

Comment: I just added these 2 lines binlog-do-db=db1name and binlog-do-db=db2name and after trying to restart the server then i ran to above issue. I even removed those 2 lines but still same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you don't have a permission problem? I found [this link](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,78674,78791#msg-78791) about Errcode 13.

Did you search other errors in system logs (messages, syslog, etc)?

Comment: Thanks man. I had permission issue. it is running now!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to go back to the configuration without the two new slaves. Make sure everything is working.

THEN, configure your slaves. You shouldn't need to change anything on the master if it was replicating already. Once you transferred your backup to the slaves and verified that they start up okay, without replicating, then set up the master information.

Can you post the changes you made to your my.cnf file(s)?

Comment: Craig,Thanks for your input. but, that is not the issue. Everytime I am trying to restart the mysql server on master machine I get this error:MySQL manager or server PID file could not be found!       [FAILED] and when I get the mysql status I get "mysql is not running but lock exists". I can't get the Master back on. 
Starting MySQL.Manager of pid-file quit without updating fi[FAILED]

Comment: My point was that you need to get the server back to a known good state.